# Communication Raspberry and Android Smartphone

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, auto, mtp

I tried to install Openauto on my Raspberry Pi 3b+ and everything seems to start normal. But when I connect my old Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 6) with it, sometimes Android Auto starts to work for some seconds and the quits. Most of the time it states an error message with "Unable to open MTP device".

When I run mtp-detect from the shell this is the result:

```
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 47
Attempting to connect device(s)
error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

I tried the [Crankshaft](https://github.com/opencardev/crankshaft) Image on the Raspberry where Android Auto works without any problems. So I guess there is a configuration problem with the android smartphone and the Raspberry.
Did anybody had a similar issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is `LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY`, in documents it states that this error code is received when the resource you are trying to access is busy. This usually happens if a program or driver has claimed the interface, meaning that 2 processes try to claim the same interface at the same time.

Try to check the processes currently running on your raspberry pi, maybe you opened multiple instances at the same time, or you are trying to use multiple programs that use the same interface.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So propably a problem when my USB Modem on the raspberry? I dont think that the serial connection to the GPS Module is disturbing the communication to the smartphone.

Comment: since I don't know how your devices are connected, I cannot say more.

Comment: I tried it without any other devices connected and also on a complete new raspbian image to install only openauto with the same result.
Is dont think that its a problem with the smartphone when it worked with the crankshaft image.